# Append canvas to document body using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I am trying to add a canvas to my html document such that it is in position 0,0 and is overlayed above all other elements. I've done some research and by all means, I think I am doing the right thing:

```
canvas.style.position = "absolute";
canvas.style.left = "0px";
canvas.style.top = "0px";
canvas.style.zIndex = "100";
body.appendChild(canvas);
```

However, the canvas appears at the bottom of the document, rather than at the top left corner, above all elements. Absolute position and setting the coordinates should do the trick, no?

Comment: Shouldn't you set the left and the top, instead of the left and the right?

Comment: sorry, that was a typo

Comment: You should probably post your mark up and your CSS. I'm guessing the canvas element is created in a div with position relative on it.

Answer (score 2):

Two methods that work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Screetop/8z5ou7L4/2/
Just add document in front of body, or search in the document for tagName body and append. Else it's just a detached element that the browser does not correctly render.

```js
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.style.position = "absolute";
canvas.style.left = "0px";
canvas.style.top = "0px";
canvas.style.zIndex = "100";
canvas.style.background = 'red';
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.style.position = "absolute";
canvas.style.right = "0px";
canvas.style.top = "0px";
canvas.style.zIndex = "100";
canvas.style.background = 'purple';
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(canvas);
```

```css
.test {
    height: 500px; 
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't know what I was doing wrong before, because I had declared:
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a new div which will be before the content and just target that like so

```
<div class="canvas-placement">
</div>
```

jQuery

```
canvas.style.position = "absolute";
canvas.style.left = "0px";
canvas.style.top = "0px";
canvas.style.zIndex = "100";
$('.canvas-placement').append(canvas);
```